# Androidx86: /android-8.1-r6 not found

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, android

I'm new to Linux and changing OS from computers, I wanted to have Lubuntu and Androidx86 in dual boot so partitioned the disk accordingly. Both OSes were installed but android86 didn't appear in GRUB, did my research and settled with re-installing everything again following this "tutorial": [How to I use Androidx86 ubuntu dualboot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454863/how-to-i-use-androidx86-ubuntu-dualboot/823757#823757?newreg=dbd84ec9b794490c8c346ecbb9a43021)

Again, didn't work, keep searching, found an alternative ([Booting Android with GRUB, but how?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517212/booting-android-with-grub-but-how?rq=1))  and configured the `40_custom` as instructed, reboot, same error message, `/android-8.1-r6 not found`.

Kept searching, found a similar question with a more recent date: [“linux” grub loader can't detect android](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/646274/linux-grub-loader-cant-detect-android?rq=1), configure the `40_custom` like the OP did, same error, his solution didn't changed anything for me.

So I gave up and decided to ask for help, been doing this for at least 3 days (I had 0 knowledge before, not even how to make a bootable USB, partitions, filesystems, command line, etc.), apologies if this type of question affects in any way to the moderators of the site.

Here some info of my system and configurations:

My partitions:

[image: My partitions]

Proof of kernel location:

[image: Proof of kernel location]

I installed Androidx86 in my `/home` mount point in the `/dev/sda3` partition:

My `40_custom` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry "Android-x86" {
set root = '(hd0,3)'
linux /android-8.1-r6/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=generic_x86 acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode SRC=/android-8.1-r6
initrd /android-8.1-r6/initrd.img}
```

I'm more than happy to provide you with any extra info you may need.

Comment: Cross-posted on Unix.SE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/659528/90391